# How can I customize facebook oauth dialog in javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I would like to change the location of the page url and I would strongly prefer to have the permissions request dialog open in a separate window.

This is the JavaScript im using:

```
  <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    status     : true, 
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true
  });
};
    (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));
  </script>
```

The dialog that comes up in a separate window doesn't show up in all browsers, freaking IE...

PHP:

```
 // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    ));

    // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) { 
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }

    //  n or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
    if ($user) {
      $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    } else {
      $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(   array(
           'scope' => 'publish_stream,user_birthday,email,offline_access',
           'next'  => 'LINK HERE',
          ));
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the whole code? the above snippet won't prompt the user to install your app!

Comment: What else are you looking for?

Comment: what is triggering the auth dialog to open? if you have a look at the [example.php](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) & the documentation, you can see that it's possible to construct the login url and redirect the user to it.

Comment: You can't use the XFBML button and not have a dialog. Also you should use `redirect_uri` instead of `next`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of attempting to subvert Facebook's JavaScript SDK, simply use the standard OAuth authentication, which allows you to redirect the user to an authentication or permissions dialog without a JavaScript popup.

See the *Server-Side Flow* section of the [Authentication documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and the *Direct URL Example* in the [OAuth dialog's documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/). Note that the [example URL](http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=email,user_birthday&client_id=123050457758183&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response/&response_type=token) in the latter documentation looks extremely similar to your second screenshot.

Comment: Yes! but how can I still using the Fbml facebook button?

Comment: The XFBML login button is part of the JavaScript SDK. Again, it would be easier to just create your own login button, compliant with Facebook's policies at http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php and elsewhere.